# WCF automatically creating Async methods

Tags: wcf

When testing my WCF SOAP service, I notice that the wcfclient tool reads in Async verions of my methods. For example, if I have a method called GetUserById (int Id), the WSDL has an additional method called GetUserByIdAsync (int Id).

Is this something I turned on by accident? Something new in .NET 4.5?

Comment: please  can you  tell  us how  you are generating the wsdl is the best  way to provide you  with the right  solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default for `svcutil` is to generate both synchronous and async taskbased methods in VS2012/.NET4.5. In VS2010/.NET 4.0 the default is to generate only synchronous methods.

SvcUtil from VS2010:

> /async                             - Generate both synchronous and asynchronous
>                                         method signatures. Default: generate only
>                                         synchronous method signatures. (Short
>                                         Form: /a)

SvcUtil from VS2012:

> /async                             - Generate both synchronous and begin/end asynchronous method signatures. Default: generate synchronous and task-based
>                                         asynchronous method signatures. (Short Form: /a)

Comment: Thanks, Anders. From VS2012/13, is there anyway to have svcutil launch without the /a flag?

Comment: Hey Jason, just curious if you were able to find the answer to not allowing /async to be called? thanks!